# How to find total number of ways to cut a sentence in individual dictionary words

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am facing in optimising a solution of a question which is a variation of [word break II](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break-ii/).

But in this question, I have to find total number of sentences without printing them. So don't want to store them.

I have written a brute force solution, where I have saved all valid sentences in a container and then finally returning it's total size.

Here is the code I have written

```
unordered_set<string> getWays(string str, unordered_set<string> &wordDict) {
    unordered_set<string> ans;
    if(str.empty()) {
        return ans;
    }
    if(wordDict.find(str) != wordDict.end()) {
        ans.insert(str);
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= str.size(); i++) {
        string pre = str.substr(0, i);
        string suf = str.substr(i);
        if(wordDict.find(pre) != wordDict.end()) {
            unordered_set<string> ans_for_suf = getWays(suf, wordDict);
            for(string s : ans_for_suf) {
                ans.insert(pre + "|" + s);
            }
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

and I am using ans.size() as the answer.
```

Here I can use dynamic programming to optimise it further, but it would not be a good approach.

So my goal is that suppose the input is

```
s = "catsanddog"
wordDict = ["cat", "cats", "and", "sand", "dog"]
```

then without returning

```
[
  "cats and dog",
  "cat sand dog"
]
```

I want to return 2, that is the size of the above returned array.

Please suggest me some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution idea using **Trie** and **DFS** :

- Build a trie using all the words in the dictionary .
- Start a dfs from the given string . Each of the characters is a node .
- Iterate over the given string , and check if you are currently in a position where any of the dictionary word ends .
- If there is a dictionary word ending here , dfs from there .

This simple recursive solution will work but not in time . Use **dp memoization** and it should be efficient .